# Micrometer Reactor Netty Http Client Metrics vs Http Client Metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, metrics, reactor-netty, micrometer

When building a Reactor Netty application I get two similar metrics. But what's actually the difference between them?

`http_client_requests_seconds` vs. `reactor_netty_http_client_response_time_seconds`

I can't figure out what the differences are in how/where they measure the response time. It's not consistent which one measures longer time.

Http Client metrics mesures longer time

```
reactor_netty_http_client_response_time_seconds_count{method="POST",remote_address="localhost:8184",status="200",uri="/api/endpoint",} 2.0
reactor_netty_http_client_response_time_seconds_sum{method="POST",remote_address="localhost:8184",status="200",uri="/api/endpoint",} 0.048153964

http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="localhost",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/api/endpoint",} 2.0
http_client_requests_seconds_sum{clientName="localhost",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/api/endpoint",} 0.167178945
```

Reactor Netty metrics mesures longer time

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="localhost",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/api/another",} 2.0
http_client_requests_seconds_sum{clientName="localhost",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/api/another",} 0.049176211

reactor_netty_http_client_response_time_seconds_count{method="POST",remote_address="localhost:8184",status="200",uri="/api/another",} 2.0
reactor_netty_http_client_response_time_seconds_sum{method="POST",remote_address="localhost:8184",status="200",uri="/api/another",} 0.046602377
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one `reactor_netty_http_client_response_time_seconds` is provided by Reactor Netty.

The measuring happens like this:

The start time is when you are about [to send the request](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/30cf3ada602d96130b7d301802cb88e15b4006d0/reactor-netty-http/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/AbstractHttpClientMetricsHandler.java#L77)

The stop time is when you receive the last package from the server [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/30cf3ada602d96130b7d301802cb88e15b4006d0/reactor-netty-http/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/AbstractHttpClientMetricsHandler.java#L111) and [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/30cf3ada602d96130b7d301802cb88e15b4006d0/reactor-netty-http/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/AbstractHttpClientMetricsHandler.java#L137-L139)

This does not include the time for obtaining the connection from the pool (this might be negligible if there is a connection in the pool, but also this might take time when there is no connection in the pool and such needs to be established). For the connection establishment there is another metric `reactor_netty_http_client_connect_time`. Also for TLS handshake there is `reactor_netty_http_client_tls_handshake_time`.

More about Reactor Netty metrics as address resolution etc., you can find in [the reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_6)

Comment: Thank you! Always nice to get an answer from the one who wrote the code.

Comment: How to enable those netty metrics in application.yml file?

Comment: For Reactor Netty metrics you can enable them only via API https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_6